# CKEditor widget receives data after it has been rendered

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Looking at the [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget-event-data) you can pass startup data to a widget:

```
editor.execCommand( 'simplebox', {
    startupData: {
        align: 'left'
    }
} );
```

However this data is pointless as there seems to be no way to affect the template output - it has already been generated before the widget's init, and also the data isn't even available at that point:

```
editor.widgets.add('uselesswidget', {

    init: function() {
        // `this.data` is empty..
        // `this.dataReady` is false..

        // Modifying `this.template` here does nothing..
        // this.template = new CKEDITOR.template('<div>new content</div>');

        // Just after init setData is called..
        this.on('data', function(e) {
            // `e.data` has the data but it's too late to affect the tpl..
        });
    },

    template: '<div>there seems to be no good way of creating the widget based on the data..</div>'

});
```

Also adding a CKEditor tag throws a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'align' of undefined" exception so it seems the data is also not passed to the original template:

```
template: '<div>Align: {align}</div>'
```

What is the point of having a `CKEDITOR.template.output` function which can accept a context, if there's no way of dynamically passing data?

The only horribly hacky solution I've found so far is to intercept the command in a `beforeCommandExec` and block it, then modify the `template` and manually execute the command again..

Any ideas to generate dynamic templates based on passed data? Thanks.

Comment: A bit late, but I got it working by modifying the code, until it's properly fixed, see the bug report I've made: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/issues/3540

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it.

Widget definition:

```
template:
   '<div class="myEditable"></div>',

init: function () {
        // Wait until widget fires data event
        this.on('data', function(e) {

            if (this.data.content) {
                // Clear previous values and set initial content
                this.element.setHtml('')
                var newElement = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( this.data.content );
                this.element.append(newElement,true);
                this.element.setAttribute('id', this.data.id);
            }

            // Create nestedEditable
            this.initEditable('myEditable', {
                selector: '.myEditable',
                allowedContent: this.data.allowedContent
            })

        });
    }
```

Dynamic widget creation:

```
        editor.execCommand('myEditable', {startupData: {
            id: "1",
            content: "some <em>text</em>",
            allowedContent: {
              'em ul li': true,
            }
        }});
```